# Project Euler Problem 11 ("Largest product in a grid") in Python

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge

Can this code in any way be improved or optimized? I'd appreciate any clever tricks or Pythonic expressions that may remove some more brute force elements from my solution.

Also, is there possibly a more intuitive way of approaching this problem that I couldn't see?

Problem statement: [Largest product in a grid](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)

> In the 20×20 grid below, four numbers along a diagonal line have been marked in red [*here bold*].
>
> `08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08`
>   `49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00`
>   `81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65`
>   `52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91`
>   `22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80`
>   `24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50`
>   `32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10`**`26`**`38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70`
>   `67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95`**`63`**`94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21`
>   `24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17`**`78`**`78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72`
>   `21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35`**`14`**`00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95`
>   `78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92`
>   `16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57`
>   `86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58`
>   `19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40`
>   `04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66`
>   `88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69`
>   `04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36`
>   `20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16`
>   `20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54`
>   `01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48`
>
> The product of these numbers is 26 × 63 × 78 × 14 = 1788696.
>
> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

My solution:

```
grid = [[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8], [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0], [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65], [52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91], [22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80], [24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50], [32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70], [67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21], [24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72], [21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95], [78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92], [16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57], [86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58], [19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40], [4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66], [88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69], [4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36], [20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16], [20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54], [1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]]

horizontal_max = max(grid[i][j]*grid[i][j+1]*grid[i][j+2]*grid[i][j+3] for i in range(20) for j in range(17))

vertical_max = max(grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j]*grid[i+2][j]*grid[i+3][j] for i in range(17) for j in range(20))

diagonal1_max = max(grid[i][j]*grid[i+1][j+1]*grid[i+2][j+2]*grid[i+3][j+3] for i in range(17) for j in range(17))

diagonal2_max = max(grid[i][j]*grid[i-1][j+1]*grid[i-2][j+2]*grid[i-3][j+3] for i in range(3,20) for j in range(17))

max_max = max(horizontal_max, vertical_max, diagonal1_max, diagonal2_max)

print(max_max)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you restricted your lines to 79 columns, [as recommended by the Python style guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), then we wouldn't have to scroll the code horizontally to read it here.

Anyway, all four loops have the same form:

```
max(grid[i][j]
    * grid[i+i_step][j+j_step]
    * grid[i+2*i_step][j+2*j_step]
    * grid[i+3*i_step][j+3*j_step]
    for i in range(i_min, i_limit)
    for j in range(j_limit))
```

given particular choices of parameters `i_step`, `j_step`, `i_min`, `i_limit` and `j_limit`. So we can implement the program as a data-driven loop over those choice of parameters:

```
print(max(max(grid[i][j]
              * grid[i+i_step][j+j_step]
              * grid[i+2*i_step][j+2*j_step]
              * grid[i+3*i_step][j+3*j_step]
              for i in range(i_min, i_limit)
              for j in range(j_limit)))
          for i_step, j_step, i_min, i_limit, j_limit
          in [( 0, 1, 0, 20, 17),  # horizontal
              ( 1, 0, 0, 17, 20),  # vertical
              ( 1, 1, 0, 17, 17),  # leading diagonal
              (-1, 1, 3, 20, 17)]) # trailing diagonal
```

If you want to avoid writing out the multiplication, then the best approach would be to define a helper function, for example using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def product(iterable):
    """Return the product of the numbers in the iterable."""
    return reduce(mul, iterable, 1)
```

and then:

```
print(max(max(product(grid[i+k*i_step][j+k*j_step] for k in range(4))
              for i in range(i_min, i_limit)
              for j in range(j_limit)))
          for i_step, j_step, i_min, i_limit, j_limit
          in [( 0, 1, 0, 20, 17),  # horizontal
              ( 1, 0, 0, 17, 20),  # vertical
              ( 1, 1, 0, 17, 17),  # leading diagonal
              (-1, 1, 3, 20, 17)]) # trailing diagonal
```

Comment: Thanks. If we wanted to use the length of the consecutive numbers (here, 4) as our parameter (instead of `i_min`, etc), e.g. so that there's less mental work involved for the user who isn't interested in understanding the logic of the algorithm, would we be able to avoid writing `grid[][]` four times? In math, one could use the ∏ (product) notation. Does Python offer a similar functionality?

Comment: See updated answer.